# How do I find Ubuntu users in my country / state

Tags: community, locoteams

I am looking to get meet other users how do I find that team.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Ubuntu Community supports Local Community Teams. You can find a list of these teams here:

http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/

This site also shows all the events that the local teams organize.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from [LoCo Teams](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/), you could also try your local LUG (Linux User Group) or general computer club (they might have a linux or Ubuntu workgroup).

Answer (score 0):

Or you can even look if your country has got a FOSS community. In my case most linux and ubuntu users I met was through a FOSS community.