# What if my State / Country doesn't have a Ubuntu LoCo Team? How can I start one?

Tags: community, locoteams

I know what an Ubuntu Team is and [where to find them](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10334/how-do-i-find-ubuntu-users-in-my-country-state), but what can users do if their area doesn't have a LoCo team?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Information (and guidelines) about how to create a new LoCo team are at Ubuntu Wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeamHowto

Answer (score 1):

The key is to start small and to not be deterred by a ton of "process" or governance (as some of the documentation would indicate.)

An Ubuntu enthusiast can host an event in their area by simply inviting people that love Ubuntu to gather in an accessible, convenient, and free (or nearly free) venue. Coffee shops are great for this. Make some small posters that say "Ubuntu enthusiasts are getting together next week. Please join us!" Then, get together and have a discussion about Ubuntu. Host a few of these and see who turns up. If there's enough enthusiasm and energy, and it looks like it's going to be a regular thing, then consider turning it into a team down the road.

If you take the time to make a group that is fun to be around before proceeding down a formal organizational path, then more people will be attracted to your events :)